# Wrong output based on $? value in bash

Tags: python, bash

I have a python script, **test.py** that contains the following:

```
import sys

def dosomething():
   a=1
   b=1
   if a == b:
      sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   dosomething()
```

And a bash script with the following contents:

```
python test.py
echo $?

if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Failed"
fi
```

The echoed value of $? is 1 which is set by the condition in the python script sys.exit(1). However, why is my bash output:

```
Success
```

instead of "Failed"? Isn't $? -eq 0 a false?

Comment: you may change `if` statement to `if python test.py; then` ....

Answer (score 1):

Because the second `$?` refers to the status code of the `echo $?` command.

If you want to use the status return more than once, save it in a shell variable:

```
python test.py
status=$?
```